# Is there a way to replace diferent values in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

So i'm trying to replace normal numbers for roman numbers, but only the last number is replaced, so i wonder if there's a way to replace diferent values

```
sample = "Carl 5, 19 century"
numbers = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', sample)
for number in numbers:
    num_int = int(number)
    roman_number = int_to_Roman(num_int)
    new_string = sample.replace(number, roman_number)

>>> Carl 5, XIX century
```

Here are some other results

```
sample = "Carl 19, 19 century"
>>> Carl XIX, XIX century

sample = "Carl 5"
>>> Carl V
```

Comment: "Only the last number is replaced": No. You never overwrite `sample`, so when you try to replace the next number it starts with the original string and replaces that number. Do `sample = sample.replace(...)` and it'll work fine

Comment: Alternatively, use `re.sub()` and pass a callable (function) to the `sub=` argument. This callable takes one argument -- the `match` object, and returns the substitution for that match, so it would likely be a simple wrapper that extracts the match string from the match object and passes it on to `int_to_Roman`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - right, but the code still won't work. `.replace` will replace numbers throughout the string even if they are part of a larger number later on. `sample = "Carl 5, 15 century"` would fail because the 5 in 15 would be replaced on the first match. The second match would try to replace 15, but its already been destroyed. The `sub=` argument is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below line in your code is taking the original string `sample` and replacing the `number` with the `roman_number` but it is stored in a variable `new_string`. In the next iteration, the code will again take the original string (which does not have the previous iteration's replacement stored) and replace the `number` with `roman_number` which is why when you are printing the `new_string` after the loop, it is just showing the last number being replaced (which is the replacement in the last iteration of the loop).

```
new_string = sample.replace(number, roman_number)
```

There are 2 fixes for this. One is to store the modified string in the sample variable itself so that the loop can take the result of the last iteration and do further replacements.

```
sample = sample.replace(number, roman_number)
```

If you want to retain the original variable `sample`, you can create a copy of the variable before the loop and do the replacement operation on the `new_string` variable.

```
sample = "Carl 5, 19 century"
numbers = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', sample)
new_string = sample
for number in numbers:
    num_int = int(number)
    roman_number = int_to_Roman(num_int)
    new_string = new_string.replace(number, roman_number)
```

Edit:

As pointed out by tdelaney, the smaller numbers part of bigger numbers can be replaced too (e.g. 5 in 15). To fix this, sort the numbers in reverse order (bigger numbers first)

```
numbers = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', sample)
numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse=True, key=len)
```

Comment: This fails for the reason tdelaney mentioned in their [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299966/is-there-a-way-to-replace-diferent-values-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment126038815_71299966)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub()` and pass a callable (function) to the `repl` argument. This callable takes one argument -- the match object, and returns the substitution for that match, so it would likely be a simple wrapper that extracts the match string from the match object and passes it on to `int_to_Roman`:

```
def int_to_Roman_wrapper(match_obj):
    return int_to_Roman(int(match_obj.group(0)))


sample = 'Carl 5, 15 century' 
new_string = re.sub(r"\d+", int_to_Roman_wrapper, sample)
```

Which gives
`new_string = 'Carl V, XV century'`

This doesn't have the problem that the `str.replace` approach does which tdelaney mentions in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299966/is-there-a-way-to-replace-diferent-values-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment126038815_71299966):

> `.replace` will replace numbers throughout the string even if they are part of a larger number later on. `sample = "Carl 5, 15 century"` would fail because the 5 in 15 would be replaced on the first match. The second match would try to replace 15, but its already been destroyed